# IOS : Custom Layouts does not work, CollectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: method not called

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, collectionview

Hello everyone I'm new in swift, and I'm trying to learn to use CollectionView, I'm following this tutorial: [Custom Layouts: A Worked Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/AWorkedExample/AWorkedExample.html)
unfortunately it is not working for me. I noticed that CollectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: method is not called and I think this could be the main problem. I put the file in the following link : [Working file](http://we.tl/brWXQIvXDP)
, if anyone knows the problem please let me help.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your custom layout class. If you change layout class to default flow layout - everything is working, so you probably need to review layout class code. I don't see any calls to super in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` and `prepareLayout` methods. That should be a start point for a research. If you are sure what you're doing, then you have to create cells by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Error found !!!
as seen from the first image the error are were where I put break points [image: first image], in the first (line 105) the Array attributes  remained nil and was not filled in the line 114.
The second mistake I found thanks to the stamp of the elements of MyAttribute.
In fact, we see in the second image 
[image: second image]from the output, that some attributes property  are null, while the frame is correct, the error was in the creation of the attribute object (line 133) of the first image.
This is the final result :
[image: final result]